# Looking for CMS for managing courses

Tags: cms

I'm looking for a good CMS for managing courses. I don't want to run these courses via the internet - so I'm not looking for an e-learning CMS.

What I need:
- create a database of courses, workshops with detailed description etc..
- allow users to register to the platform, subscribe for courses
- create profiles for tutors - with a short description etc.
- besides normal courses I would like to create some courses "in plans" - if there will be enough people interested in such course, we will try to organize it
- I also need to have the ability for users to send us information about courses they demand (i.e. they go to a page of the course that was run some time ago and click "do it again!" ;) )
- create the ability to give us a feedback after the course (polls etc)

I was thinking about moodle or dokeos but since I don't need the e-learning platform (only platform to manage the courses...) don't you think it's a little bit too sophisticated tool in my situation?

What CMS would you recommend?

Answer (score 1):

Drupal is incredibly powerful and extremely customizable. You can do pretty much everything you require with Drupal using plug-ins and by customizing it.

Another option would be to create your own CMS, but this would raise the cost. If cost isn't an option, this may be your best bet as you could get EXACTLY what you want and, if you need more options later, you could have them added in provided the CMS is written in such a way that makes it easy "plug-in" new technologies.

However, before making the leap to getting a custom CMS, [take a look at Drupal](http://drupal.org/) and some of its plug-ins to get an idea of whether or not it's exactly what you need. It's free, but you will likely incur some cost using Drupal unless you customize and set it up yourself.

I agree with you about the eLearning Platform. It sounds like your needs won't be met with a platform like that and what you require is too different to modify a pre-existing eLearning platform to your specifications. Best of luck!

Comment: Are there any plugins/extensions that you would recommend?

Answer (score 0):

Moodle is hardly sophisticated and is used by some brick-and-mortar universities. You can always just not use some of its features. You do not even have to install it to try it out, since you can download a [virtual appliance](http://bitnami.org/stack/moodl), for example from bitnami.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a custom php mysql system would work best.

Comment: Why does it have to be PHP with MySQL? Why not any other another language/database combo? What makes this the best option over others? There are tons of content management systems written in other languages. Expand.

Comment: PHP and Mysql are the most popular. Its been used for years and there are many programmers who can do the work. There are many tools available free. It can scale to very big. BTW the popular CMS's , Wordpress, Drupal,Joomla are written in PHP Mysql.